# How to add new device (iPhone SE) to Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to add the iPhone SE to my list of emulated devices for testing. After I add in all of the device info it still has the "Add" button grayed out. Is there a certain way you have to add the device info?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Device Pixel Ratio should be a decimal or whole integer.

Comment: The real iPhone SE DPR is 2 for anyone looking for it. Source: https://www.danhendricks.com/2017/05/adding-iphone-galaxy-chrome-mobile-emulated-devices/